# List all unresolved pull request comments

Tags: github, github-api, octokit, octokit-js

We are using the [@octokit/rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/rest#api-docs) client to fetch all of the comments on a pull request:

```js
client.pulls
  .listComments({
    owner,
    repo,
    pull_number: 34,
    per_page: 100,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data.length);
    console.log(result.data[0]);
  });
```

How if at all can we list only the unresolved comments? There does not appear to be a property in the data that indicates whether someone has resolved the comment or not.

Comment: Maybe you can get reviews in the PR using [this](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#octokit-routes-pulls-list-reviews) and then for each pending review get comments using [this](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#octokit-routes-pulls-get-comments-for-review). Haven't tested this yet.

Comment: To get pending reviews I think you can check for the `state` of the PR as `CHANGES_REQUESTED`. Again not implemented completely.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai the `state` that you have mentioned is of the PR. What the OP needs is the state of the comments on a PR's review.

Comment: @MadhuBhat Yes, that is correct. Its just an assumption that if the particular review request is still on `CHANGES_REQUESTED`, then some comments on that particular review are still not resolved.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai but even if all comments of a review request are resolved, the state of the PR still stays as `CHANGES_REQUESTED`. It changes only of it is approved or dismissed. But anyhow, the OP requires to list the comments based on the status and not if they are present or not.

Answer (score 8):

Using [GitHub's v4 GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), the [GraphQL API Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) (to explore/build my query), the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (to simplify calling the GraphQL API), and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (to filter the results); I came up with the following solution (written as a bash script to ease calling, but the same principles would apply if calling the GraphQL API from code as well):

```bash
# Usage:
#   Retrieve unresolved review comments
#     ./pr-unresolved-review-comments myorganisation myrepo 1337
#
#   Count of unresolved review comment threads
#     ./pr-unresolved-review-comments myorganisation myrepo 1337 | jq length

gh api graphql -f owner="$1" -f repo="$2" -F pr="$3" -f query='
  query FetchReviewComments($owner: String!, $repo: String!, $pr: Int!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
      pullRequest(number: $pr) {
        url
        reviewDecision
        reviewThreads(first: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              isResolved
              isOutdated
              isCollapsed
              comments(first: 100) {
                totalCount
                nodes {
                  author {
                    login
                  }
                  body
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
' | jq '.data.repository.pullRequest.reviewThreads.edges | map(select(.node.isResolved == false))'
```

The specific fields that you include as part of the GraphQL query are customisable, but this seemed to give me what I needed.

The output of running the above script will look something like the following:

```json
[
  {
    "node": {
      "isResolved": false,
      "isOutdated": true,
      "isCollapsed": false,
      "comments": {
        "totalCount": 7,
        "nodes": [
          {
            "author": {
              "login": "0xdevalias"
            },
            "body": "This is an unresolved comment that is important!",
            "url": "https://github.com/myorganisation/myrepo/pull/1337#discussion_r559294516"
          },
          ..snip..
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  ..snip..
]
```

To list unresolved comments against **all** open PRs for a repo, this script can be used instead:

```bash
# Usage:
#   Retrieve all unresolved review comments for a repo
#     ./pr-unresolved-review-comments myorganisation myrepo

gh api graphql -f owner="$1" -f repo="$2" -f query='
  query FetchReviewComments($owner: String!, $repo: String!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
      pullRequests(first: 30, states: OPEN) {
        edges {
          node {
            url
            reviewDecision
            reviewThreads(first: 100) {
              edges {
                node {
                  isResolved
                  isOutdated
                  isCollapsed
                  comments(first: 100) {
                    totalCount
                    nodes {
                      author {
                        login
                      }
                      body
                      url
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
'  | jq '.data.repository.pullRequests.edges[].node.reviewThreads.edges | map(select(.node.isResolved == false))'
```

Comment: Very nice; I've turned this [into a script](https://github.com/inkarkat/git-extensions/blob/master/bin/hub-prcomments) that renders parts of the JSON into ASCII output.

Answer (score 5):

On **GitHub.com**, not all comments under a pull request have the `resolved/unresolved` status, but only the comments as part of a review. And **GitHubs's v3 API**, which **octokit** uses, doesn't provide any such status as part of the response of `GET` on comments of a review, and a sample response of the same is :

```json
    [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/comments/1",
        "id": 10,
        "node_id": "MDI0OlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0UmV2aWV3Q29tbWVudDEw",
        "pull_request_review_id": 42,
        "diff_hunk": "@@ -16,33 +16,40 @@ public class Connection : IConnection...",
        "path": "file1.txt",
        "position": 1,
        "original_position": 4,
        "commit_id": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
        "original_commit_id": "9c48853fa3dc5c1c3d6f1f1cd1f2743e72652840",
        "in_reply_to_id": 8,
        "user": {
          "login": "octocat",
          "id": 1,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
          "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "body": "Great stuff",
        "created_at": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z",
        "updated_at": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1#discussion-diff-1",
        "pull_request_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/comments/1"
          },
          "html": {
            "href": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1#discussion-diff-1"
          },
          "pull_request": {
            "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

So essentially, I don't think your requirement can currently be served by GitHub's v3 API or Octokit. You can see more about it on GitHub v3 API's [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#get-comments-for-a-single-review)

Comment: That's my sense too. I might have to do a fair amount of programmatic work to filter out the resolved comments.

Answer (score -3):

I can get resolved/unresolved comments by [list-review-comments-on-a-pull-request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-review-comments-on-a-pull-request).

Try `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/comments`

Comment: What field are you using to determine whether the comments have been resolved/unresolved with this method?